# Как "foreach" вернуть к первому элементу коллекции?

Tags: c#, foreach

**КОД**

```
dv1 = new DataView(table3);
dv1.RowFilter = pole + " = '" + crit + "'"; // фильтр
dv1.Sort = "p_n"; // сортировка по возрастанию ВАР. 

// DataView. Отобразить в dataGridView1
dataGridView1.DataSource = dv1;

foreach (var obj in dv1) // foreach 2 СПИСОК 
{
    DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)obj;
    DataRow r = drv.Row;

    if (// условие)
    {
        // выполнение ...

        // ВОПРОС !!!
        // Возврат к первому элементу коллекции
    }

    // код...                 
}
```

**ВОПРОС**
Как сделать, чтобы "в конце if (// условие)" код переходил на выполнение "foreach" сначала?

Comment: ну либо сделать [GOTO](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/goto), либо рекурсивную функцию

Comment: замените `foreach` на `for`, тогда возврат к первому элементу: `i = 0;`

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский Не могли бы вы показать примером, а то не совсем понимаю как применить `GOTO`, либо `рекурсивную функцию` в моём случае

Comment: Выделить форич в функцию и вызывать ее в себе же

Comment: @Андрей Сделал так https://codeshare.io/GkpmKV. Думаю вам стоит оформить ответ.

Comment: @GlWhitefoo Сделал так: https://codeshare.io/2j40k3. Думаю вам стоит оформить ответ.

Comment: @koverflow. Ок.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Замените цикл `foreach` на `for`, тогда возврат к первому элементу будет выглядеть типа `i = 0;`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dv1.Count; ++i)
{
    DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)dv1[i];
    DataRow r = drv.Row;

    if (// условие)
    {
        // выполнение ...

        // Возврат к первому элементу коллекции:
        i = -1;   // Обратите внимание, именно -1, т.к. перед следующей
        continue; // итерацией будет выполнено выражение в разделе итератора
    }

    // код...                 
}
```

[for (справочник по C#)](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/for)

Но будьте внимательны, изменение счетчика цикла вне заголовка ухудшает читаемость кода, поэтому старайтесь избегать таких решений

Answer (score 3):

Ну GOTO не очень хорошо хотя и можно. А рекурсия с foreache - упадет. Пока он работает, нельзя изменять его элементы. Как следствие для решения этой задачи надо просто запускать цикл по новой. Например так:

```
// DataView. Отобразить в dataGridView1
dataGridView1.DataSource = dv1;
bool stop = false; //переменная для сброса повтора
while (!stop) //цикл повтора
{
    foreach (var obj in dv1) // foreach 2 СПИСОК 
    {
        DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)obj;
        DataRow r = drv.Row;

        if () // условие возврата к первому элементу (запускаем цикл по новой)
        {
            break;
        }
        if (// условие) //условие остановки всех повторов
        {
            stop = true;
            break;
        }

        // код...                 
    }
}
```

Comment: `А рекурсия с foreache - упадет` - таки а зачем рекурсию с foreach? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Выделить форич в функцию и вызывать ее в себе же.

**КОД**

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    cnt = 0;
    fnk_DtVw_frch();
  }

  public void fnk_DtVw_frch() // ФУНКЦИЯ
  {
    foreach (var obj in dv1) // foreach 2 СПИСОК 
    {
      DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)obj;
      DataRow r = drv.Row;

      if (cnt == 0) // проверяем условие
      {                    
        cnt = 1; // меняем условие

        fnk_DtVw_frch();
        break;
      }

     // код... 

    }
   }
```